# Why does Sachi come to Kirito's bed? Does this imply more than what we see?

Tags: sword-art-online

Midway through episode 3, Sachi comes to Kirito's room at night holding her pillow.  Given that we just saw Kirito comforting Sachi under the bridge, it's natural to assume that she is there for platonic comfort.

However, it's also natural to assume that she's there for non-platonic comfort.

Can we assume any more than what we see happens?  As is later revealed in the anime, adult themes and capabilities are present within the game, so the players can get it on if they want to.

The focus of this episode definitely seems to be on Sachi, and we can presume that later events have a significant impact on Kirito.  SAO Abridged continually refers to the events in this episode throughout the rest of it's first season.  In both SAO and SAO Abridged, the center of this is Sachi, not the entire Black Cats guild.

Given these details, can we assume that Kirito and Sachi got it on that night?

Answer (score 3):

**Why does Sachi come to Kirito's bed?** Because she seeks comfort. She expressed her fears early on in this episode and she probably just seeks friendly company instead of sex since she's having trouble falling asleep. After seeing Kirito's true level during that, however, [she felt more at ease](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Sachi). **Does this imply more than what we see?** No, it doesn't. I watched this episode again just to make sure and **no, nothing else happened on that night.** While she seems to have feelings for Kirito, Kirito only exhibits 'Platonic' love for them, as shown in the same episode when he promised to himself that he would protect his friends. The idea you pointed out that 'adult themes and capabilities are present within the game' is exactly the reason why I believe nothing happened. The anime had no problem showing his and Asuna's bed scene so why would they omit his and Sachi's if it really happened? Unless, of course, no sex really happened that night.